# How to let the calendar take the 100% width and height and not overflow the window

Tags: css

https://83540d4b.ngrok.io/calendar.htm

I tried to apply

```
.nx-cal-table{
    height: 100vw;
}
```

To make the calendar take the full height of window and also not overflow the window which means the y-scroll bar won't appear.
However, it didn't work at all.

any idea?

[image: inline]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying with viewport width.

Try with viewport height:

```
.nx-cal-table 
{ 
   height: 100vh; 
}
```

Comment: would that still take the full of the window width. I also need that effect